# Strong mac should allow adversary to generate valid tags?

Tags: cryptography, hmac

I am reading the book "introduction to modern cryptography" by katz ([https://eclass.uniwa.gr/modules/document/file.php/CSCYB105/Reading%20Material/[Jonathan_Katz%2C_Yehuda_Lindell]_Introduction_to_Mo(2nd).pdf?fbclid=IwAR1hf1OTKAhf4ZHvswERpcZ3ZVDQMxHuP2FWRg2tvlo3-tUMSdFIPLWZR_8](https://eclass.uniwa.gr/modules/document/file.php/CSCYB105/Reading%20Material/%5BJonathan_Katz%2C_Yehuda_Lindell%5D_Introduction_to_Mo(2nd).pdf?fbclid=IwAR1hf1OTKAhf4ZHvswERpcZ3ZVDQMxHuP2FWRg2tvlo3-tUMSdFIPLWZR_8))

On page 114, I stumbled over this statement:

```
As defined, a secure MAC ensures that an adversary cannotgenerate a valid tag on a new message that
was never previously authenticated.But it does not rule out the possibility that an attacker might        
be able togenerate a newtagon a previously authenticated message. That is, a MAC guarantees that if 
an attacker learns tagst1, . . .on messagesm1, . . ., then it will not be able to forge a valid tag t 
on any message m 6 ∈{m1, . . .}. However,it may be possible for an adversary to ”forge” a different 
valid tagt′16=t1 on the messagem1. In general, this type of adversarial behavior is not a 
concern. Nevertheless, in some settings it is useful to consider a stronger definition of security for 
MACs where such behavior is ruled out.
```

Here it claims that it would not break a mac scheme if for any generated tag t, generated by mac(m,t)
an adversary is able to generate a valid tag t' that is different from a another valid, using the same message m.
This doesnt make sense to me at all. If we generate a tag from message m, then if we next generate another tag' from the same message m, then that must mean that we are using two different keys, and then the tag t' couldnt pass when we try to verify it?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not related to programming and is better suited for [crypto.se]

Comment: It is really clear. The new tag is a tag for an old message, not a new message and a tag for that. You are already assuming the message1 has a valid signature with tag1 and the adversary just produced another tag2 for the message1. What is the gain of the adversary?